# Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment successfully uploaded DSYM

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

error: Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment

```
Fetching upload-symbols settings...

Successfully submitted symbols for architecture arm64 with UUID 3d4f0b957bef316eb2605de709aa6dd7 in dSYM: /Users/rajusharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/raju-eirtxuvrxhjrqdcpmgkotmwinesb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/raju.app.dSYM
[32mSuccessfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols[0m


Command PhaseScriptExecution emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask] to improve your question. Make sure to include a [example] showing what you have done so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Could not get GOOGLE\_APP\_ID in Google Services file from build environment" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620215/could-not-get-google-app-id-in-google-services-file-from-build-environment-err)

Comment: This answer really helped me. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/57627011/18053577](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57627011/18053577)